# Substituting brown sugar for corn sugar

Tags: sugar, fermentation

An apfelwein recipe I've made in the past calls for 2 lbs of corn sugar for primary fermentation.  The next go-round when I make a batch, I'm thinking of substituting some brown sugar (not a lot, perhaps 1 part brown sugar, 3 parts corn sugar).

My question: is corn sugar and brown sugar the same, pound-for-pound, as far as using it for primary fermentation?  Or is there a conversion rate I should follow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using light brown sugar, for all intents and purposes they are the same.  They should both ferment to 100%.

Dark brown sugar has more molasses in it and there are some unfermentable sugars in molasses. That being said, its such a small percentage that I simply wouldn't worry about it. Were are talking fractions of a percent loss of ABV.

So, essentially substitute brown sugar of any variety at a 1:1 ratio to corn sugar.

Heh, if you used brown sugar, enough cinnamon sticks and nutmeg during the short boil and enough vanilla after fermentation completes you could make liquid apple pie. :-)